# Adding $n\pi$ to the phase when estimating the phase velocity of a sound wave through a material

Tags: fft, python, phase, frequency-response

### Setup

I'm estimating the phase velocity in a wooden table by using an actuator and 3 sensors. The actuator sends out a chirp and on the table there are 3 accelerometers with distance $d$ between them. I am using chirp compression to make it "easier" to work with. Then I look at the chirp compression from sensor 1 and sensor 2, and cut out the interesting part of the signal, but keep the time delay. A window function is applied to make the cutted-out part start and end at zero.
The chirp hits sensor 1 first.

### Phase calculation (in python)

Calculating the phase by unwrapping the angle of the fft relationship between sensor 1 and 2.

```
S1f = np.fft.fft(sens1_compressed)
S2f = np.fft.fft(sens2_compressed)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(sens1_compressed), 1/Samplerate)
phase1 = np.unwrap(np.angle(S2f/S1f))
```

### Calculating the velocity

The phase can be expressed as follows:
$$\phi = \omega \tau - \frac{\omega \Delta d}{v_{ph}}$$ The $\omega \tau $ part is taken care of in the fft as the time delay was kept.

I can solve for $v_{ph} = - \omega \Delta d / \phi$.
In python:

```
v_ph = -2*np.pi*freq*distance/(phase)
```

`distance` is $\Delta d$

#### Note

I am only looking at frequencies from 1k-40kHz

### The question

Sometimes when doing this with different measurements (I've done the experiment multiple times), I have to add $\pm n \pi$ to the phase expression to get a phase velocity that makes sense. I understand what the shift does, but not why I can or need to do it.

Here is an example where the phase velocity is correct:
[image: phase vel]

Here is an example where the phase velocity is not correct (multiplying by $-\pi$ will "fix" it):

[image: phase vel 2]

Anyone have any input on why this happens and why I can or can't do it? The shift in phase by adding or subtracting $n\pi$ is so small but the change in the velocity plot is big.

Comment: Something seems off, speed of sound in wood should be between 3000m/s and 5000m/s.  In general it's also better to use the group delay instead of the phase delay or just cross correlate in the time domain. Without looking at your actual data and the details of how "compress" it, it's hard to tell

Comment: @Hilmar , The speed of sound is not off, as what i am looking at is the bending waves in the plate. I should have mentioned that in the post. The reason I am looking at the phase here, is that it is much easier to find with the data I have. The experiment is done to find out more about the plate. Would like to find the group velocity as well, but this is a bit more difficult in python. Can you elaborate this sentence: "In general it's also better to use the group delay instead of the phase delay or just cross correlate in the time domain"

Comment: Typically the easiest way to find the delay between two highly correlated signals is to calculate the cross correlation and look for the location of the peak. If you have signal to noise problems you can  bandpass filter both signals first (with the same bandpass) to focus on your frequency range of interest. If you have a delay that depends on frequency the "group delay" is  better estimate how fast "information travels" than the phase delay. If the delay is relative constant, both quantities are more or less the same

Comment: @Hilmar, I have already tried this, and it does not give accurate enough result. It will give the approximatly velocity of the high frequencies that arrive first. The reason I need the it to be accurate is that it is used to estimate when reflections from walls should arrive. And as the signal being sent in is broadband in frequency I need an "accurate" estimation per frequency.